# How to set parameter in class instance JS?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am working on JS mocha tests and I want to move parser to separate file and export it like a module. If I need to get parameter from CSV file I would just pass an argument into class instance `pars.getAcc()` and get parameter from CSV file. The problem is when I am using class instance to parse csv I'm getting `undefined`. Seems like I do something wrong...

parser.js

```
const parse = require('csv-parse')
const fs = require('fs')
const csvData = []
const filepath = "../balance.csv"

export default class Pars{
    getAcc(num){
    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        .pipe(
            parse({
                delimiter: ','
            })
        )
        .on('data', function(dataRow){
            let line = dataRow[num].split(',')
            csvData.push(line)
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            csvData[0].toString()
        })
    }
}
```

accounts.js

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import Pars from '../utils/parser'

describe('account ID', ()=>{
    
    let pars = new Pars()

    it('parser', ()=> {
        console.log(pars.getAcc(1))
    })
})
```

Output:

`account ID undefined`

Comment: `getAcc()` doesn't return anything, therefore it *returns* `undefined`

Comment: How to make it to return ID?

Comment: you can't ... since *streams* are asynchronous, there's no way to return a result *synchronously* - you could return a Promise maybe ... not sure how to set that up in mocha, but I'm sure there's plenty of information in the documentation ... of course, you'll first need to figure out how to return that Promise

Comment: The current code in the question does not print the output you mentioned because the current code returns the `id` variable which is an empty string: `''`.